# Load Remote JSON File for Autocomplete Flexdatalist in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, wordpress

I have a json file which contains addresses, states and postcodes information. I utilized autocomplete flexdatalist to show suggestions while user types in the address. It works when the json file is local (data: 'myr-mini.json'), but when i use a url which starts like "http:/.." it doesn't work. Kindly help me on this one. Thanks in advance.

```
<input id="cp_address" name='Myr Address' type='text' class='flexdatalist' placeholder='Write your country name' size="40">
<input id='Postcode' name='Postcode' type='text' placeholder='enter zipcode' size="40">

<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js?ver=1.12.3'></script>    
<script src="scripts/jquery.flexdatalist.js"></script>
<script>
     $('#cp_address').flexdatalist({
     minLength: 2,
     selectionRequired: true,
     visibleProperties: ["value","state"],
     searchContain: true,
     searchIn: 'value',
     searchDelay: 200,
     noResultsText: 'No results found for "{keyword}"',
     data: 'https://studentsklm.com/wp-content/themes/classipress/myr-mini.json'
}).on("select:flexdatalist",function(event, data){
  $('#Postcode').val(data.postcode);
});
</script>
```

Comment: do you see, in your browser console, the message **No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'**? If yes, it's clear the reason. For more info you can search for **CORS**

Comment: I searched for CORS, not sure what i need to do. I tested the script on my website with the full url but it didn't work. I tried to include the json file same as the page path that is showing the form, but wordpress has different pathing style since the pages are auto generated by php. I'm thinking of linking the json file (5mb) just like scripts!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my json is a big file and i can't use services like **myjson** which has CORS enabled, therefore i had to figure out a way to do it, i waited for hours for an answer from someone to fix my issue, kept on refreshing this page many times, unfortunately i didn't get help, thats why i'm answering myself, hopefully it helps someone:)

**Solution:** I slightly changed the data with notepad++ find and replace, then i added the javascript autocomplete routine  and saved it a javascript file named 'postmyr.js'. Then i included it my webpage nearly the end of body tag. (put the full url path)

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://yourdomain.com/wp-content/themes/classified/scripts/postmyr.js?ver=4.8'></script>
```

From this:

```
[
    { "postcode": "01000", "value": "Alor Redeh", "postoffice": "Kangar", "state": "Perlis" },
    { "postcode": "01000", "value": "Alor Tok Terang", "postoffice": "Kangar", "state": "Perlis" },
    { "postcode": "01000", "value": "Bohor Gelam", "postoffice": "Kangar", "state": "Perlis" },
    { "postcode": "01000", "value": "Jalan Abi Tok Hashim", "postoffice": "Kangar", "state": "Perlis" },
    { "postcode": "01000", "value": "Jalan Alor Sena", "postoffice": "Kangar", "state": "Perlis" },
]
```

To This:

```
var postmyr = [
    { postcode: '01000', value: 'Alor Redeh', postoffice: 'Kangar', state: 'Perlis'},
    { postcode: '01000', value: 'Alor Tok Terang', postoffice: 'Kangar', state: 'Perlis'},
    { postcode: '01000', value: 'Bohor Gelam', postoffice: 'Kangar', state: 'Perlis'},
    { postcode: '01000', value: 'Jalan Abi Tok Hashim', postoffice: 'Kangar', state: 'Perlis'},
    { postcode: '01000', value: 'Jalan Alor Sena', postoffice: 'Kangar', state: 'Perlis'},
];

    $('#cp_address').flexdatalist({
    minLength: 2,
    selectionRequired: true,
    visibleProperties: ["value","state"],
    searchContain: true,
    searchIn: 'value',
    searchDelay: 200,
    noResultsText: 'No results found for "{keyword}"',
    data: postmyr
}).on("select:flexdatalist",function(event, data){
    $('#cp_zipcode').val(data.postcode);

});
```

The above code i just showed 5 rows of my data, utleast you get the point, my full data has 54050 rows which works fine with no issues even with mobile devices.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a CORS issue with trying to hit the URL for the JSON data. Below is a sample using myjson.com which has CORS enabled, and typing in "Per" into the country input brings back results:

```js
$('#cp_address').flexdatalist({
  minLength: 2,
  selectionRequired: true,
  visibleProperties: ["value", "state"],
  searchContain: true,
  searchIn: 'value',
  searchDelay: 200,
  noResultsText: 'No results found for "{keyword}"',
  data: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/v588t'
}).on("select:flexdatalist", function(event, data) {
  $('#Postcode').val(data.postcode);
});
```

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js?ver=1.12.3'></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-flexdatalist/2.1.3/jquery.flexdatalist.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-flexdatalist/2.1.3/jquery.flexdatalist.min.css" />

<input id="cp_address" name='Myr Address' type='text' class='flexdatalist' placeholder='Write your country name' size="40">
<input id='Postcode' name='Postcode' type='text' placeholder='enter zipcode' size="40">
```

Comment: Hi Woodrow, thanks for the assist. Yes with myjson it works. Earlier i tested a smaller json file it worked perfect, however my address json is a big file and i tried to upload it in myjson website many times but it was not successful with an error showing "413 Request Entity Too Large". The json file has many rows, i minified it but still considered big.

Comment: Can someone help me please. Tell me how to use my own json file in my website and be able to call it by using http url or any other way, in the autocomplete data parameter and fixing the CORS as well. I will really appreciate that time taken to assist.

Answer (score 0):

you have to change event from select:flexdatalist... to change:flexdatalist.

Try change your code as to following:

```
...
  valueProperty: 'postcode',
  data: postmyr
}).on("change:flexdatalist",function(event, data){
    $('#cp_zipcode').val(set.value);
```